# How can I prove that the restricted parametrization of a surface in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ ia a diffeomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, parametrization

$S$ is a regular surface of the space and I need to prove that if $X:U\subset\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow S$ is  a parametrization of $S$, then $X:U\subset\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow X(U)$ is a diffeomorphism.

The book gave a brief explanation, but I don't get it. It says that if I take another parametrization $X$ and use the fact that composition of $X^{-1}$ and $Y$ be a diffeomorphism, then $U$ and $X(U)$ are diffeomorphics.

Obs. The book definition of parametrization is that $X$ is homemorphism to his image with injective diferetial in all points of his domain.

Comment: What precisely is your book's definition of a parametrization?

Comment: I edited, it was take from the book, Curves and Surfaces by Ross and Montiel

Comment: by the definition what you wrote is a diffeomorphism, yes, because a parametrization is defined as an injective immersion. If the differential is injective then you only need to use the inverse function theorem.

Comment: You didn't put the complete definition (and part of what you've typed still doesn't make sense — "take another parametrization $X$"?). $X$ is assumed $C^1$ or smooth, with injective differential. So the inverse function theorem tells you that it has a local $C^1$ inverse. That, together with the fact that $X$ maps homeomorphically to its image, tells you that $X$ is a diffeomorphism.